# How to test component with API call in react?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, fetch, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I am having trouble with testing react component that fetch data from API and renders on screen. 
This is the error that I get.

```js
     ● Company Details › renders company details with given data

    expect(received).toMatch(expected)

    Expected substring: "Google"
    Received string:    "no name provided"

      18 |     );
      19 | 
    > 20 |     expect(getByTestId('company-name').textContent).toMatch('Google');
         |                                                     ^
      21 |     expect(getByTestId('sponsors-visa').textContent).toMatch('Yes');
      22 |     expect(getByTestId('description').textContent).toMatch('this is a company description');
      23 |   });

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/components/company-detail/CompanyDetail.test.js:20:53)
```

My test file `CompanyDetail.test.js` code :

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import CompanyDetail from '../../../components/company-detail/CompanyDetail';
    import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
    describe('Company Details', () => {
      let mockData;
      beforeEach(() => {
        mockData = { match: { params: { id: 4 } } };
        jest.mock('../../../components/effects/use-fetch.effect');
      });

      it('renders company details with given data', async () => {
        const { getByTestId } = render(
          <BrowserRouter>
            <CompanyDetail {...mockData} />,
          </BrowserRouter>
        );

        expect(getByTestId('company-name').textContent).toMatch('Google');
        expect(getByTestId('sponsors-visa').textContent).toMatch('Yes');
        expect(getByTestId('description').textContent).toMatch('this is a company description');
      });
    });
```

Code that I want to test (`CompanyDetail.js`)

```
    import CONSTANTS from '../../constants/constants';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    import useFetch from '../effects/use-fetch.effect';

    const CompanyDetail = (props) => {
      const { id } = props.match.params;
      const { name, description, jobs, known_to_sponsor_visa } = useFetch(`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies/${id}`);
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Container>
            <Row className="m-2">
              <Col>
                <Card>
                  <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>
                      <h3 data-testid="company-name">{name ? name : 'no name provided'}</h3>
                    </Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text data-testid="sponsors-visa">
                      <b>Known to sponsor work visa: </b>
                      {known_to_sponsor_visa ? known_to_sponsor_visa : 'No data'}
                    </Card.Text>
                    <Card.Text data-test-id="description">{description}</Card.Text>
                  </Card.Body>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    };

    export default CompanyDetail;
```

Just in case if it needs `use-fetch.effect.js`:

```js
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    const useFetch = (url) => {
      const [dataArray, setData] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
        try {
          const fetchData = async () => {
            const res = await fetch(url);
            const dataArray = await res.json();
            setData(dataArray.data)
          }
          fetchData();

        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      }, [url]);

      return dataArray;
    };

    export default useFetch;
```

I could test it by sending data via props but I have no idea how can I mock data to test that url to receive id and render it into specific place. Any help would be appreciated. I know why error is there because i have not passed any company name as Google to check. Problem is how can i test that by passing some dummy data .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - how do I unit test an API call in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61576450/react-how-do-i-unit-test-an-api-call-in-jest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `useFetch` is expected to be asynchronous any way and this may affect how the component works, it needs to be mocked in more complicated way than Jest spy that returns a value. The request itself can be mocked instead of entire `useFetch`:

```
let data = { name: 'Google', ... };
spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockResolvedValue({ json: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data }) });

...

expect(getByTestId('company-name').textContent).toMatch('no name provided');
await waitFor(() => expect(getByTestId('company-name').textContent).toMatch('Google'));
```

Comment: Hello @Estus , Thank you for you help. I am getting this error after implementing it. `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of '(0 , _useFetch.default)(...)' as it is undefined.`

Comment: I updated the code, the response should have `data` property. In case you didn't remove `jest.mock`, consider doing this, it may cause this error too.

Comment: It solved the problem I mentioned above. Yes i removed `jest.mock` as well and changed `waitFor` to `waitForElement` .  I am getting the error that I posted on question from this line `await waitFor(() => expect(getByTestId('company-name').textContent).toMatch('Google'));` . [Here](https://gist.github.com/20was/2415c2e542523739b842a540038a7491) is my gist . Can you please tell me where did I wrong ?

Comment: I see. waitFor and waitForElement are different functions. waitForElement expects a selector, it shouldn't work here, also it's deprecated.

Comment: when I dig into node_modules at  the `@testing-library` has `wait-for-element.js` . Whenever I use `waitFor` it shows me error : `TypeError: (0 , _react2.waitFor) is not a function` . To make it work with `waitForElement` , what change do I have to make ?

Comment: I'm not sure waitForElement supports selectors to match contents, so you likely can't make it work. waitFor is supposed to be there, https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro . It's essential for blackbox testing, you won't get far without it. I see it in the package. Consider updating it to the latest version.

Comment: Thank you . I finally made it work . Need to upgrade `react testing library`  and had to install `jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen` . Thank you so much.